# List all recent activities

Tags: activities, activity

I'm a newbie with CiviCRM.. sorry if my questions sound stupid. As I understand, activities are central to this CRM. Yet, I can't find a quick way (e.g in the menu) to display all recent activities. I have to digs into reports (3 or 4 clicks) or have a "preview" within the CiviCRM dashboard.
What am I missing?
Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SE! You need to use Find Activities under the Search menu. This allows you to filter by date (and other things). If you want something more complicate try Advanced Search with Display as Activities.